# Optimization of found points to line intersections

Tags: optimization

I have currently a pattern of points. Through an algorithm I obtain quite accurately the points, but I would like to make the points even more accurate.

The pattern looks like:

```
x       x

    x

x       x
```

It may vary since I see it from a camera (projection changes), so i can't use perpendicular or parallel constraints. However I was thinking of using the line preservation property (that 2 points should always be in a line even when projected), and to take advantage of the intersection of such lines, since the points should be in such place.

I was thinking of maybe to do something like minimizing the distance of the line intersection to the points I have obtained, but not sure how to put to them all at once to have a global optimization of the points.

I saw a possible way to do it for 1 point and n lines [here](http://cal.cs.illinois.edu/~johannes/research/LS_line_intersect.pdf), however I am not sure how to incorporate the rest of the points to do them all at once.